# join or select in on multiple fields

Tags: mysql

(The example that follows is hypothetical, but illustrates the concept).

Using MySQL, say I have 2 tables:

```
userFromID  userToId  moreInfo
1           2         cat
1           3         dog
4           1         bear
3           4         fish
```

And...

```
userId  someInfo addlInfo
1       m         32
2       f         33
3       m         25
4       f         28
```

And I want to query for a user id, and get back joined info from both tables for all users that share a relationship with user1.

assume that the first table has something like `alter table thatFirstTable add unique index(userFromId, userToId)` so there won't be any duplicates - each relationship between the two ids will be unique.

it doesn't matter who's the "from" or "to"

so the desired result would be something like this, if queried for relationships with user id: 1

```
userId  moreInfo  someInfo  addlInfo
2       cat       f         33
3       dog       m         25
4       bear      f         28
```

Thanks.

/EDIT this "works" but I suspect there's a better way?

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN friends ON friends.userFrom = users.id OR friends.userTo = users.id WHERE users.id != 1 AND friends.userFrom = 1 OR friends.userTo = 1
```

/EDIT2 - I updated the sample output to better reflect the goal

Answer (score 0):

try this query::

```
select tbl2.userid,tbl1.moreinfo,
tbl2.someinfo,tbl2.addinfo
from tbl1 join tbl2
on (tbl1.usertoid = tbl2.userid and tbl1.userfromid = 1)
```

Comment: thanks for your post.  however, that query doesn't get back relationships where the userTo matches the user id passed.

Answer (score 0):

You should just join the tables  with the query below.

```
select u.userId, f.moreInfo, u.someInfo, u.addlInfo
from users AS u INNER JOIN friends AS f ON u.userId = f.UserToId
where f.userFrom = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your post.  As I commented to the other poster, passing an id should give back all relationships with that id, whether it was userFrom or userTo, and should exclude the user with the passed id as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Tested and 100% working

```
select a.userToID, a.moreInfo, b.someInfo, b.addInfo from tbl1 a 
left outer join
tbl2 b on a.userToID = b.userId
where a.userFromID = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for your post.  again this fails to get all relationships - remember that the "userFrom" or "userTo" parts don't matter - if there's a relationship (either from or to), it should be returned, minus the queried id.